# LEfSe - LDA Scores' Vertical Lines

Tags: python, conda, bioinformatics

I am using [LEfSe](https://bitbucket.org/biobakery/biobakery/wiki/lefse) on Google Colab with Python 2.7 using the following commands

```
!conda install -c biobakery lefse 

!format_input.py hmp_aerobiosis_small.txt hmp_aerobiosis_small.in -c 1 -s 2 -u 3 -o 1000000 

!run_lefse.py hmp_aerobiosis_small.in hmp_aerobiosis_small.res 

!plot_res.py hmp_aerobiosis_small.res hmp_aerobiosis_small.png
```

Everything is working, but there is a problem in LEfSe's plot such that it is drawing LDA scores' vertical lines with solid lines instead of dashed ones. Here are examples of the image from the Tutorial (left) and what I am seeing (right)

[image: image with dashed lines] [image: image with solid lines]

I was checking the help of `plot_res.py`, but I could not find any argument to change in order to produce the one similar to [what is in the tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/biobakery/biobakery/wiki/lefse#rst-header-id6).

**What do I need to do in order to show dashed vertical lines for the grid?**

Comment: Not sure, but if I had to guess, I think it has to do with them using a different (earlier) version of Matplotlib than you do in your Conda env.

Comment: The Docker shows it using Matplotlib 1.5.1, whereas Conda likely installed 2.x or even 3.x, since it's an unconstrained requirement. I'd try restricting Conda to use version 1 of Matplotlib. Either that, or you need to editing their code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the [line 111](https://bitbucket.org/nsegata/lefse/src/9adc3a62460eddf268366b0f3d01a55ea84dfb40/plot_res.py#lines-111) of the `plot_res.py` script:

```
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
```

for this options:

```
ax.xaxis.grid(linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8,
              dashes=(2, 3), color='gray', alpha=0.5)
```